# Render a HTML template during a PDF request in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, server-side-rendering

I am trying to pin point how to use `render_to_string` and get the HTML before converting it to PDF.

Right now, I am using `PDFKit` to re-request the HTML version of the same URL, but it is plain ugly:

```rb
def my_report
  # do some smart logic first

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # this responder renders HTML normally

    format.pdf do
      # recreate the request URL with the .html extension instead of .pdf
      url = my_report_url(format: :html, params: params)

      # PDFKit fetches HTML from the URL
      kit = PDFKit.new(url, page_size: 'A4', orientation: 'Portrait')

      # PDFKit converts the HTML to PDF
      send_data(kit.to_pdf, filename: 'my_report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8', disposition: 'inline')
    end
  end
end
```

The solution seems to be to use `render_to_string` to render HTML within the `format.pdf` block, something like this:

```rb
format.pdf do
  # render the HTML in memory - fails with ActionView::MissingTemplate
  html = render_to_string :my_report, formats: [:html]

  # PDFKit uses the in-memory HTML (saves a roundtrip)
  kit = PDFKit.new(html, page_size: 'A4', orientation: 'Portrait')

  # PDFKit converts the HTML to PDF
  send_data(kit.to_pdf, filename: 'my_report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8', disposition: 'inline')
end
```

This always fails with the `ActionView::MissingTemplate` error. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ensured that the expected view actually exists? If so update the question to indicate it.

Comment: @max The view exists, because the my_report.html works and returns HTML as expected.

Comment: @Eyeslandic PDFKit converts HTML to PDF, either by loading it from a URL or directly from an HTML string. Right now, when PDF is requested, another request in the background is done by PDFKit to fetch the HTML for conversion. I would like to avoid that step and render HTML in-memory before handing it over to PDFKit.